# How to prevent OnItemClickListener work when long click performed?

Tags: android, gridview, listview, onlongclicklistener

I have a gridview and i want its items to act different if user performs click or long click that is why i am using OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener but when long click happens both listeners react.I want to perform only OnItemLongClickListener.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {   
   return true;
}
```

return true will be prevent click event to be continue. It will be perform only `OnItemLongClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AdapterView.setOnItemLongClickListener](/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener)). GridView inherits AdapterView, so you can invoke that method on GridView too.

Comment: I am using AdapterView.setOnItemLongClickListener already but i am using setOnItemClickListener too and they both react to the long clicks i want to prevent OnItemClickListener react to the long clicks.

Answer (score -1):

In order to intercept long cliks (aka tapping) you should imlement [GestureDetector.OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html)